# Why are unit tests greyed out in Visual Studio 2015 for SQL Server project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have created and added a SQL Server project into my Visual Studio 2015 c# solution.

I would like to do unit testing for my stored procedures. After right clicking on one of the procedures, it is showing **create unit test** as greyed out:

[image]

I did get the most recent SSDT update.

**Why is the create unit test option greyed out?**

Here is the information about my Visual Studio version:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
- Installed Version: Professional
- Visual C# 2015    Microsoft Visual C# 2015
- SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50730.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
- TypeScript   1.7.6.0 TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was build, fix a few errors, and voila:
[image]

Comment: Correct - a valid model is needed in order to create unit tests. Otherwise the necessary metadata needed to general parameters etc. may not be available.